# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 392000 into shape (28,28)

Tags: python-3.x, theano

Codes form:

> https://github.com/wepe/MachineLearning/blob/master/DeepLearning%20Tutorials/cnn_LeNet/convolutional_mlp.py

This's an error When running CNN test.I had tried some methods but didn't work.

Codes:

```
def evaluate_lenet5(learning_rate=0.1, n_epochs=200,
                dataset='mnist.pkl.gz',
                nkerns=[20, 50], batch_size=500):
    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(23455)
```

Reshape matrix of rasterized images of shape (batch_size, 28 * 28) to a 4D tensor, compatible with our LeNetConvPoolLayer (28, 28) is the size of MNIST images.

```
# Load data
datasets = load_data(dataset)
train_set_x, train_set_y = datasets[0]
valid_set_x, valid_set_y = datasets[1]
test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]

# Calculate the number of batches
n_train_batches = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
n_valid_batches = valid_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
n_test_batches = test_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
n_train_batches /= batch_size
n_valid_batches /= batch_size
n_test_batches /= batch_size

index = T.lscalar()  
x = T.matrix('x')   
y = T.ivector('y') 
layer0_input = x.reshape((batch_size, 1, 28, 28))
...
```

And the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 392000 into shape (28,28)
```

These information(Input) appears below the error:

```
Toposort index: 41
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(int64, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(500, 784), (2,)]
Inputs strides: [(6272, 8), (8,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', array([28, 28], dtype=int64)]
Outputs clients: [[InplaceDimShuffle{x,x,0,1}(Reshape{2}.0)]]
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

392000 = bath_size(500) * 28 * 28, so, i don't know why...

I'm very appreciate if someone can fix this problem.
Thx!

Comment: Are you sure that to begin with, x has the shape of `(392000, )`?

Comment: Make sure your `batch_size` variable is 500.

Comment: Can you tell me how to check batch_size is 500?    I have try few times but error either. Maybe  the problem is 'reshape array'?

Comment: `print(batch_size)`